# What is L[L[3]] in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im studying for a computer science final right now and I do not understand how this works at all:

```
L = [ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 ]

30. L[L[3]] - 1 is?
(A) * -1
(B) an error
(C) 8
(D) 4
(E) 7
```

The answer is -1.. SO to test how this works I just did L[L[3]] and the answer is 0, then i did L[L[4]] and thar equals 5, then i did L[L[1]] that gave a 9 but if I go L[L[2]] I get a list index out of range error. Im beyond confused here Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 11):

`L[3]` is `5`, `L[L[3]]` is `L[5]` is `0`, and `0 - 1` is `-1`.

Answer (score 4):

These sort of problems are best worked one step at at time, from the inside out.

So, L[3] gives you 5. Use this value (5) as the index into the list again, i.e., L[5] and this gives you 0. Finally, 0 - 1 = -1, your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is analogous to [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) with Math functions (e.g. f(g(x))).

We take our list and work from the inside-out, so we get `L[L[3]] -> L[5] -> 0`, and subtract one from that to get `-1`.

When you take the next for-instance, `L[L[1]] = L[6] -> 9`.  Finally, `L[L[2]] = L[7] -> IndexError`.

It's all about evaluating a composite indexing (or function, for that matter) from the inside-out.

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through the answer by showing the intermediate results, even though they are not displayed:

`L[3]` is 5, `L[L[3]]` is therefore `L[5] = 0`, and `L[L[3]] -1 = 0-1 = -1`

Answer (score 0):

L[2] = 7 and the list only has only 7 elements, that is indice 0..6. So accessing L[L[2]] = L[7] is out of range...

Answer (score 0):

it says,  get the number at l[3]    which is 5,  then use that, so get the number at l[5] which is 0,   then subtract 1.... ta dah!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer broken down in steps:

L = [ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9 ]

L[L[3]] - 1 = -1

L[3] = 5, so L[L[3]] = L[5] = 0